# Decimal to string conversion issue

Tags: c#

```
Math.Round((ClosePrice - OpenPrice), 5) = -0.00001
```

But When I convert it into tostring it gives "-1E-05"

```
Math.Round((ClosePrice - OpenPrice), 5).ToString() = "-1E-05"
```

Why this is so ? How can I get "-0.00001"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use format specifier as demonstrated on [MSDN's Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)

```
double foo = -0.00001;
Console.WriteLine(foo.ToString("f5"));
```

Answer (score 4):

`ToString()` chooses a format based on the value being formatted to achieve the most compact representation. If you would like to choose a specific format, you need to use the `ToString(string format)` overload instead. For example, if you call

```
Math.Round((ClosePrice - OpenPrice), 5).ToString("N5")
```

you will get `"-0.00001"` string as the result.

Answer (score 2):

Every class inheriting from `object` (and therefore any class) has a `.ToString()` method. What it outputs depends on weather it was overwritten and if it was, how it was overwritten (i.e. what did the implementer *want to* give out as string. Its the same process you would go through if implementing a `.ToString()` method for one of your classes.

This is as to "Why" - the "How" has been answered by others.